# PHP5 utf-8 error (cron job of syscp)

Tags: php, locale

I installed *SysCP* on Debian 5 and I keep getting the following error message from a cron job:

> Warning: Terminal locale not UTF-8, but UTF-8 locale is being forced.
>            Screen output may not be correctly printed.

I haven't found a solution yet. The default locale of the machine *was* de_DE.UTF-8 but I changing this entry did not solve the problem. I digged through everything I could find on the web. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.